# Notification system in spring web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, push-notification, notifications

I am currently developing java/jee application,which has 2 projects:backend and frontend projects which are communicating via micro services.I am using mysql as database and i want to create a notification system so what is recommended to be used?

Comment: have you referred [this](https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-web-socket-user-notifications) example using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options.

- JMS/ActiveMQ with JMSTemplate
- AMQP/RabbitMQ or Kafka with RabbitTemplate/KafkaTemplate (Preferred for beginners)
- Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka (High throughput/Advanced usecase microservices)

More [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-amqp) for AMQP

More [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) for Cloud Stream.

If you're starting out it's fine using the second option. It's easy to migrate to the third one and you should be using Spring Cloud (specially designed for microservices) for that. The third one is the easiest and have lesser codes.